# How do I open up the Chromium source code as a project within Visual Studio Community?

Tags: visual-studio, chromium

I have followed the instructions here [(https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md)) to download the Chromium source code.  It took about an hour!  I understand how, "Chromium uses Ninja as its main build tool along with a tool called GN to generate .ninja files."  Basic newbie question:  How do I open up the Chromium source code as a project within Visual Studio Community? Also, is there anyway to do the build from within Visual Studio?  Thx in advance!

Comment: Did you read that page? It describes it step by step

Comment: That is a typical snotty, demeaning "Stack Overflow Guru" response.  If you search this page for the word "project" there are seven occurrences, none in regard to creating a project within Visual Studio.  Nor is there any information on doing the build within VS!  The so-called "Gurus" on Stack Overflow should be more concerned with patiently helping others rather than egotistically voting down questions.  This was a major issue a few years ago.  I thought the Stack Overflow mgt corrected this.

Comment: Also, there is no way Mr. White could have read the page himself in the two minutes after I posted the question.  Did he have the page memorized?  My suspicion is that there are hundreds of projects within the Chromium project and there is not one master project.  Someone who has worked with Chromium, and is a kind and patient teacher, could probably answer this.

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/windows_build_instructions.md#Editing-and-Debugging-With-the-Visual-Studio-IDE

Comment: If you plan to edit the source code by following the above method, it will very slow as Chromium is a very big project. The whole Visual Studio will be slow even on a high end machine. The other thing that you can do is unload most of the projects when that solution is created. This will make VS more responsive.